# Deja dup can't see previous backups after ubuntu 17.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I was running and backing up ubuntu 17.04.  I upgraded to ubuntu 17.10.  When I tried to restore my files from 17.04 to 17.10 deja dup says there are no backups.  I can see the back files with nautilas but deja dup won't see them. I ran back up with 17.10 and that is the only back deja dup sees.

Comment: This is a nightmare scenario! But I believe it can be resolved. Can you provide some details? What, *exactly* did you enter for the storage location in the Deja-dup fields?  And what, *exactly*, is the location of your backup files as seen in Nautilus?

Comment: I don't seem to have an option.  Although when I did the one back up for 17.10 I pointed it to the same drive and deja dup sees the one back up for 17.10 which is at the same location (usb hard drive) that all the other back ups occupy.  17.10 deja dup doesn't see the 17.04 backups...just the one 17.10 back up.  Do I have to reinstall 17.04 and forget about 17.10.  By the way, I tried reinstalling deja dup and recieved the message the it is already the latest version.

Comment: If you could give the information I requested, it would really help diagnose your issue.

Comment: I am using the gui duplicity and all the backups (17.04 and one for 17.10) are in the same location.  Nautilus sees all the backups, but deja dup seems to only see the 17.10 back up located in the exact location as the 17.04 backups.